# Console Error on bootstrap datepicker revalidation

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker, bootstrapvalidator

For ***Validation datepicker is working fine***. After Saving the form; During Revalidating Date getting error as:

> **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'group' of undefined**

Error disappears by removing this line

```
$('#ovrseastrvlrqst').bootstrapValidator('revalidateField', 'trvlreqapldt');
```

you can find code in JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/t38gcjrg/10/

but i cannot simulate error in JSFiddle, Actual Source code and JSFiddle are almost same except there is validation for someother form fields.

**UPDATED:** Use this JSfiddle to Simulate issue https://jsfiddle.net/ahssyah2/11/
Try to Change date in `Apply Date*` field; In Browser(*Press F12*) Console you will get Error.

> What could cause this Javascript console error?

**Note:- Error occurs only when editing previously saved Forms. No Errors on Saving Fresh Forms.**

**Using :** `Bootstrap DatePicker, BootstrapValidator, Chrome Browser, PHP`

---

as User @Shehary mentioned few other Errors; so tried to fix that and I updated JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ahssyah2/15/ now i got an new issue.

In my case `Projected Related` and `Third Party Funded` will be checked or may not be checked. Based on these two CheckBox i'll dynamically Add/Remove Validation.

If i try to uncheck CheckBox i get Error as

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'not' of undefined**

on **bottstrapValidator.js**

> *Note:-*
>
> **Solved :** Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'group' of undefined
>
> New Issue: **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'not' of undefined** Also Form is not Submitting Properly *(if i check and uncheck
>   CheckBox then its submitting otherwise Submit Button is Disabled)*

---

All Above mentioned issues solved in this JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ahssyah2/19/ but; still have below issue

> **ISSUE:** Form Not Submitting

Comment: second fiddle, there is an error in console log `TypeError: this.options.fields[field] is undefined` in firefox and when same fiddle open in chrome there is an error in console log `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'validators' of undefined` SideNote: these 2 errors is showing when fiddle load and your question is about `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'group' of undefined` so wondering which error is real :/

Comment: @Shehary updated new JSFiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/ahssyah2/15/ can you check this

Comment: don't see any error now in jsfiddle.net/ahssyah2/15 on date change

Comment: @Shehary date change issue solved but i got new issue. can you check question

Comment: i checked the update in question, that's why deleted the last comment, i suggest to move all the change events after bootstrapvalidator code, there is no reference to support this theory e.g initialize all plugin code before bootstrapvalidation code and then bootstrapvalidator code comes and then revalidate changes in any field after bootstrapvalidator code

Comment: but to support the above theory, here is an example, this is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ahssyah2/11/ you first posted where you have error `Cannot read property 'group' of undefined` and this is where I resolved it but moving datepicker change events after bootstrapvalidtor code https://jsfiddle.net/ahssyah2/12/ and the error `Cannot read property 'group' of undefined` is gone but didn't post it as solution or answer because there were other errors

Comment: @Shehary yes i agree with your above comment. Now scenario is when `uncheck` CheckBox in form it will `removeField` from bootstrapValidator. According to my understanding **Issue is Because** No `addField` is called at this point of time. Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: @Shehary is there anyway to call `boostrap Validator 'addField'` by default when CheckBox is `checked`?

Comment: @Shehary solved issue by adding `if($('#prjrltd').is(':checked')){ addValidator_projectfields(); } if($('#thrdprtyfnd').is(':checked')){ addValidator_thrdprtyfund(); }` Thanks for helping

Comment: glad I was of any help, you should make the solution as answer to help the future user.

Comment: @Shehary Now No JavaScript Error But Form not Submitting. Check this https://jsfiddle.net/ahssyah2/19/ if you can help me :(

Comment: it means somewhere some element change event is changing but not updating and submit button basically getting disabled

Comment: the problem is with checkbox, first submit the form, button get disabled then remove check from checkbox and button get enabled and form submitted so the problem is with icheck plugin